# Android DataBinding increases Compilation time

Tags: android, data-binding, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-databinding

After using DataBinding in my project, it increases the compilation time by almost 3 time.

Anyone experienced this issue and any one have solution to this issue

android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

here is the Gradle Process,

Gradle console output should be something like this (produced also without Data Binding dependency), where most tasks show "UP-TO-DATE":

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Launcher    30m34.33s   (total)
:Launcher:crashlyticsUploadRelease  3m48.28s
:Launcher:crashlyticsUploadRelease  3m47.65s
:Launcher:crashlyticsUploadRelease  3m47.36s
:Launcher:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease    2m10.91s
:Launcher:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease    1m15.67s
:Launcher:mergeHDebugResources  1m14.40s
:Launcher:transformClassesWithDexForDebug   1m11.57s
:Launcher:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug  50.019s 
:Launcher:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease    45.933s 
:Launcher:transformClassesWithDexForDebug   44.197s 
:Launcher:mergeReleaseResources 42.840s 
:Launcher:transformClassesWithDexForRelease 39.647s 
:Launcher:transformClassesWithDexForDebug   37.544s 
:Launcher:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug  35.999s 
:Launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac   30.436s 
:Launcher:compileDebugJavaWithJavac 30.246s 
:Launcher:mergeDebugResources   27.041s 
:Launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac   26.340s 
:Launcher:mergeReleaseResources 26.216s 
:Launcher:transformClassesWithDexForRelease 21.634s 
:Launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac   20.928s 
:Launcher:transformClassesWithDexForRelease 20.263s 
:Launcher:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug  17.442s 
:Launcher:compileDebugJavaWithJavac 16.619s 
:Launcher:mergeReleaseResources 13.947s 
:Launcher:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug    55.383s 
:Launcher:clean 13.641s

Comment: you app is running a clean task. `:Launcher:clean 13.641s`
This is not an incremental build so it won't be up to date.
On the other hand, 55 seconds of `Launcher:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug` seems way too long. we have sample project w/ more than a 100 files which takes a few seconds, i wonder how it takes 55 seconds in your app.

Comment: Are you using crashlytics? If so, have you tried to set ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false ?